Remove gaps with xOffset
Is there a way to not have gaps at non-existing data when using x/yOffset? In the example below, category B only has 1 group (x) and I would like that bar to be centered at the B-tick.
source = pd.DataFrame({
    "Category":list("AAABCCC"),
    "Group":list("xyzxxyz"),
    "Value":[0.1, 0.6, 0.9, 0.7, 0.6, 0.1, 0.2]
})

alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x="Category:N",
    y="Value:Q",
    xOffset="Group:N",
    color="Group:N"
)



I don't think there is any straightforward way of doing that. You could maybe compute a new column that checks how many groups there are within each category and assigns an offset value accordingly.

maybe you should use "facet()" method to separate each category:
facet = chart.facet(
column=alt.Column('Category:N', header=alt.Header(labelAngle=0))
).resolve_scale(
x='independent'  
)
facet.display()

